# Web scraping certain web page cannot finish

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

So i'm learning web scraping with node 8, followed this
npm install --save request-promise cheerio puppeteer

The code is simple

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const url = 'https://www.examples.com'; //good

rp(url).then( (html) => {
    console.log(html);
}).catch( (e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Now if url is examples.com, i can see the plain html output, great.

Q1: If yahoo.com, it outputs binary data, e.g.
�i��,a��g�Z.~�Ż�ڔ+�<ٵ�A�y�+�c�n1O>Vr�K�#,bc���8�����|����U>��p4U>mś0��Z�M�Xg"6�lS�2B�+�Y�Ɣ���?  ��*
 why is this ?

Q2: Then with nasdaq.com, 
const url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/earnings/report/msft';
the above code just won't finish, seems hangs there.

Why is this please ?

Comment: Can you share some of the "binary data" that is output for yahoo.com?

Comment: I have tried using another HTTP client package called "Axios", and the result is the same, maybe it's just how Yahoo return there data?

Comment: @FelixFong maybe, i don't know much about these stuff, but if you run in browser, everything is fine. The 2nd question even confuses more, just returns nothing and hangs there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about Q2, but I can answer Q1.

It seems like Yahoo is detecting you as a bot and preventing you from scraping the page! The most common method sites use to detect bots is via the [User-Agent header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent). When you make a request using `request-promise` (which uses the `request` library internally), it does not set this header at all. This means websites can infer your request came from a program (instead of a web browser) because there is not User-Agent header. They will then treat you like a bot and send you back gibberish or never serve you content.

You can work around this by [manually setting a User-Agent header](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers) to mimic a browser. Note this seems to work for Yahoo, but might not work for all websites. Other websites might use more advanced techniques to detect bots.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const url = 'https://www.yahoo.com'; //good

const options = {
  url,
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Mobile; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0'
  }
};

rp(options).then( (html) => {
    console.log(html);
}).catch( (e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Q2 might be related to this, but the above code does not solve it. Nasdaq might be running more sophisticated bot detection, such as checking for [various other headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

Comment: No problem! In general, websites want you to use their APIs instead of web-scraping because it is easier to monetize APIs. Nasdaq has a [real-time quote API](https://data.nasdaq.com/DOD.aspx) that costs money, which is probably why they block bots from web-scraping. I would suggest looking for other APIs to solve your problem instead of web-scraping. [This](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-free-realtime-REST-APIs-for-getting-NASDAQ-DOW-stock-quotes) might be a good place to start.